# Summarise an a XML data

Tags: siblings, summarization

I have an input in the format below which pulls all movie lists with actor names (key is movie) and I need to summarize the data on actor perspective.

```
<Response>
   <dpDeviceName>TEST</dpDeviceName>
   <dpTxnId>10412325</dpTxnId>
   <dpTimespamp>2014-06-19 08:51:41 UTC</dpTimespamp>
   <StoredProcedureResult>
         <resultSet>
            <metadata>
               <columnInfo index="1" nullable="false" name="FNAME" precision="3" scale="0" type="SQL_CHAR"/>
               <columnInfo index="2" nullable="false" name="LNAME" precision="30" scale="0" type="SQL_CHAR"/>
               <columnInfo index="3" nullable="false" name="ID" precision="3" scale="0" type="SQL_CHAR"/>
               <columnInfo index="4" nullable="false" name="MOVIE" precision="3" scale="0" type="SQL_CHAR"/>
            </metadata>
            <row>
               <column>
                  <name>FNAME</name>
                  <value>TOM</value>
               </column>
               <column>
                  <name>LNAME</name>
                  <value>CRUISE</value>
               </column>
               <column>
                  <name>MOVIE</name>
                  <value>Jack Reacher</value>
               </column>
               <column>
                  <name>ID</name>
                  <value>123</value>
               </column>
            </row>
            <row>
               <column>
                  <name>FNAME</name>
                  <value>TOM</value>
               </column>
               <column>
                  <name>LNAME</name>
                  <value>CRUISE</value>
               </column>
               <column>
                  <name>MOVIE</name>
                  <value>TOPGUN</value>
               </column>
               <column>
                  <name>ID</name>
                  <value>123</value>
               </column>
            </row>
            <row>
               <column>
                  <name>FNAME</name>
                  <value>MORGAN</value>
               </column>
               <column>
                  <name>LNAME</name>
                  <value>FREEMAN</value>
               </column>
               <column>
                  <name>MOVIE</name>
                  <value>SEVEN</value>
               </column>
               <column>
                  <name>ID</name>
                  <value>128</value>
               </column>
            </row>
         </resultSet>
   </StoredProcedureResult>
</Response>
```

I need this to be formatted in the below manner :

```
<library>
        <Actor>
               <firstname>TOM</firstname>
               <lastname>CRUISE</lastname>
               <movielist>
                    <movie>Jack Reacher</movie>  
                    <movie>TOPGUN</movie>  
               </movielist>
               <id>123</id>
             </Actor>
             <Actor>
               <firstname>MORGAN</firstname>
               <lastname>FREEMAN</lastname>
               <movielist>
                    <movie>Seven</movie>  
               </movielist>
               <id>128</id>
             </Actor>
    </library>
```

I am stuck at the place where i have to make a reference to next row from current for each loop to decide if movie list has to continue or block has to be closed. Any guidance here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention the point that the rows are going to in sequence for the id

Comment: In which programming language you need to implement this?